# dont bind checkBox when not checked - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I some CheckBox that Generated dynamicly .
In my viewmodel I have :

```
    public List<Guid> Booleanfields { get; set; }
    public List<bool> Booleanfieldvalue { get; set; }
```

when Checkbox is Checked I can get List of `Bool` (Booleanfieldvalue ) and All of them are true , but when I dont checked checkbox  ,mvc binder dont bind with `false` value .  `Booleanfieldvalue` just Fill when checkbox is checked.

**Code**

I generate checkboxes like :

```
 @foreach (var item in fields)
        {
@switch (item.FieldTypeId)
                    {
                        case FieldType.Checkbox:
     <input type="hidden" name="Booleanfields" value="@item.Id" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="Booleanfieldvalue" class="dynamiccheckbox"
}
 />
```

to solve it I use this jquery scripts ,

```
    $(".dynamiccheckbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(this).val("true");
    else{
        $(this).val("false");

    }
});
```

but it doesnt work .
[image]
how can I do it ?

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are not successful controls and do not post back a value (setting it to false has no affect). Generate you html correctly using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Booleanfieldvalue)` inside a `for` loop and delete the script

Comment: @StephenMuecke for each item I need html like `<input type="hidden" name="Booleanfields" value="@item.Id" />
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Booleanfieldvalue" class="dynamiccheckbox" />` because i have to list one of them is `boolean` and nother is `guid` ,

Comment: No you do not! Look at the html generated by the `CheckBoxFor()` method to understand the html you do need to generate in order to post back correctly. And if there is any relationship between `Booleanfields` and `Booleanfieldvalue` then your model is also wrong

Comment: Based on your edit, it gets even worse. You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls and expect it to bind. You need a `for` loop so that the `indexers` are added, but because of your `if` block, you may get indexers which do not start at zero and are not consecutive, so it will fail anyway.

Comment: You really should be using a view model to represent what you want to edit so you can strongly bind to it, but if you want hacks like this, then include a hidden input for `Booleanfieldvalue` (and remove `name="Booleanfieldvalue"` from the checkbox), and then update the value of the hidden input in your script (not the checkbox)

Comment: my form generated dynamicy and featch fields and field type from datatbase , i handle for `text,dropdown,file` just remain checkbox , i cant use viewmodel .

Comment: _Cant use view model_? (probably the most ridiculous statement a MVC developer can make)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I cant use viewmodel , because I dont have any data for fill viewmodel , I just create form . I cant tell you very good because my english is bad , when i do it I upload project here and you can see it , thanks for answer, good job

Comment: You can use a view model - and hopefully it wont be too long before you realize it :)

Comment: I think you should probably take a look at on how the DefaultModelBinder works. Here's [Phil Haack's post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) on how to bind a List or what you call a dynamically created control

Answer (score 0):

It Worked Fine For Me
$(".checkkBoxId").attr("checked") ? alert("Checked") : alert("Unchecked");